# How to create Animated Expandable Floating Action button like below, without 3rd party Library?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm struggling to build the animated floating action button below. Please help me with some working solution. I have tried using Expandable FAB button code from flutter.dev website and tried with some plugins and Animated container with stack. But it's still no use.

Please help me guys.

[image]

Comment: Seems like neumorphic  design.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a packages called flutter_speed_dial that gets this done 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial

This is an example that you can see it and check it for yourself

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar( 
             title: Text("Speed Dial Floating Action Menu"),
             backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
            direction: SpeedDialDirection.left,
            icon: Icons.menu, //icon on Floating action button
            activeIcon: Icons.close, //icon when menu is expanded on button
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, //background color of button
            foregroundColor: Colors.white, //font color, icon color in button
            activeBackgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, //background color when menu is expanded
            activeForegroundColor: Colors.white,
            visible: true,
            closeManually: false,
            curve: Curves.bounceIn,
            overlayColor: Colors.black,
            overlayOpacity: 0.5, //background layer opacity
            onOpen: () => print('OPENING DIAL'), // action when menu opens
            onClose: () => print('DIAL CLOSED'), //action when menu closes

            elevation: 8.0, //shadow elevation of button
            shape: CircleBorder(), //shape of button
            
            children: [
              SpeedDialChild( //speed dial child
                child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                label: 'First Menu Child',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                onTap: () => print('FIRST CHILD'),
                onLongPress: () => print('FIRST CHILD LONG PRESS'),
              ),
              SpeedDialChild(
                child: Icon(Icons.brush),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                label: 'Second Menu Child',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                onTap: () => print('SECOND CHILD'),
                onLongPress: () => print('SECOND CHILD LONG PRESS'),
              ),
              SpeedDialChild(
                child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                label: 'Third Menu Child',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                onTap: () => print('THIRD CHILD'),
                onLongPress: () => print('THIRD CHILD LONG PRESS'),
              ),

              //add more menu item children here
            ],
          ),

          body: Container()
       );
  }
}
```